# MKMapView is not showing annotated points

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to show the location of my current location and random 5 points points like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    otherlat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currentLatitude doubleValue]];
    otherlong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currentLongitude doubleValue]];

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    longi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    lati = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *la = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *lo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    la = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"20", @"21", @"42", @"51", @"75", nil];
    lo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"60", @"21", @"82", @"181", @"35", nil];

    for (int x = 0; x < [la count]; x++) {
        otherlat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[la objectAtIndex:x] doubleValue]];
        otherlong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[lo objectAtIndex:x] doubleValue]];
        [longi addObject:otherlong];
        [lati addObject:otherlat];
    }

    myAnnotation *myAnnotation1 = [[myAnnotation alloc] init];
    for (int y = 0; y < [lati count]; y++) {  
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = [[lati objectAtIndex:y] doubleValue];
        theCoordinate.longitude = [[longi objectAtIndex:y] doubleValue];

        myAnnotation1.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

    static NSString *myAnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:myAnnotationIdentifier];
    customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplepin.png"];
    customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return customPinView;
}
```

However, the mapview only shows the my current location, and none of the other 5 locations. I do not understand why it is not showing the other 5 locations because I do

```
  [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
```

Comment: Key issue, move annotation alloc/init inside `for` loop. You also can't have longitude that exceeds 180.0. You could simplify your array logic significantly. Your `viewForAnnotation` should probably use `customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple` rather than the png. Your `viewForAnnotation` really should be attempting to `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` before creating a new one. No point in showing callout if you don't set the `title` property on your annotation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only add 1 annotation. you do it 5 times, but you always overwrite the previous coordinate.

```
//only 1 is allocated and then used/modified in every iteration of the loop!
myAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[myAnnotation alloc] init];
for (int y =0; y < [lati count]; y++) {  
    ....
```

you need to create not 1 myAnnotation1, but ..... 5 separate ones:

```
//allocate & add in each iteration of the loop!
for (int y =0; y < [lati count]; y++) {  
    myAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[myAnnotation alloc] init];
    ....
```